# !important width changes for no reason

Tags: css

In css:

```
.dot {
  width: 9px !important;
  height: 9px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

In html:

```
<button type="button" class="dot"></button>
```

In browser (Says its 16px and when i expand to see why it just shows the 9px):

[image: size incorrect]
[image: 9px but actually 16px]

Tested in IE and Chrome, both are 16x9px.

If i set width and height to 15x15 px then it appears fine (even without !important).

If i set width & height to 10 then its 16x10px in browser.

I also tried setting width, max-width, min-width (and heights) to 9px !important, still 16x9px.

Comment: `<button>` elements have default browser styles that may be interfering. Either use a CSS reset file or try this with `border: 0; padding: 0`

Comment: it's the padding add `padding:0;`

Comment: Yup its padding, thanks Jon & Zohir

Comment: Why doesnt it happen on 15x15 tho.. (becomes 16x15 as if it has padding to fill till 16px on width)

Comment: @LukaKostic check out the explanation in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be familiar with `box-sizing` property which determines how the width and height are calculated, in chrome the default value for `box-sizing` set on a button is `border-box`

**[border-box](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp): The width and height properties includes content, padding and border**

Let's now talk about your case:

**Content:**

```
<button type="button" class="dot"></button>
```

The button has no text which means the width of it's content is `0px`

**Padding:**

Default `padding` on the button applied by the user agent(chrome in this case) is

```
padding-top: 1px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 6px;
```

**Border:**

*we only care about the width of the border*

Default `border`  on the button applied by the user agent(chrome in this case) is

```
border-top-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 2px;
```

---

*we'll talk about the width alone, because it's pretty much same thing for the height*

Without applying any styles, let's sum it all up

`left border 2px` + `left padding 6px` + `content 0px` + `right padding 6px` + `right border 2px`

So the overall width of a button by default will be 16px.

Now when you say `width:9px` you explicitly setting the width in which `border+padding+content` should live in, but their width is wider so it expands.

> Why doesnt it happen on 15x15 tho.. (becomes 16x15 as if it has padding to fill till 16px on

That's because `16px` is the exact amount of space `border+padding+content` need to live, that's why you see no change.

Now if you set the width to be wider than `16px` what will change is the content's width because border get set width `border property` and padding width `padding` property.

## Solution

So to fix this we need to reset those predefined styles `padding` and `border`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('button').getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
button {
  width: 9px;
  padding: 0;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: Could you include 'padding: 0px;' so it has the answer to the question and not just an explanation (for someone whos just looking for the answer)